# Error concatenating characters in swift

Tags: swift, concatenation

I tried to concatenate two characters in Swift but it shows me the error

> Binary operator can't be applied on two character operands.

```
let a: Character = "A"
let l: Character = "l"

let al = a + l
```

Operator overloading is supported by Swift's Strings so why not Character?

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html, `You can’t append a String or Character to an existing Character variable, because a Character value must contain a single character only.`  You will have to create a string and `.append()` each character individually to add them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want/need to be able to "concatenate" 2 `Character(s)` using the `+` operator you can define this function.

```
func + (left:Character, right:Character) -> String {
    return "\(left)\(right)"
}
```

As Skrundz said in its comment, an instance of `Character` can contain only 1 character so the output of the function is going to be a `String`.

Now:

```
let a : Character = "A"
let b : Character = "B"
let ab = a + b // -> the String "AB"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can append a character to a string

```
let a: Character = "A"
let l: Character = "l"

var al = ""

al.append(a)
al.append(l)

println(al)  // "Al"
```

or concatenate two strings

```
let a = "A"
let l = "l"

let al = a + l   // "Al"
```

Answer (score 2):

simple explanation : `Character` is a type of a single value, logically there can't be any concatenation. You need to "upcast" to String

```
let al = String(a) + String(l)
```

(even `let al = String(a + l)` does not work)

Answer (score 0):

List most of possibilities of concatenating two characters

```
let character1: Character = "a"
let character2: Character = "b"

let result = String(character1) + String(character2)
let result = "\(character1)" + "\(character2)"
let result = "\(character1)\(character2)"
let result = "" + [character1, character2]
var result = ""; result += [character1, character2]
var result = ""; result.append(character1); result.append(character2)
var result = [String(character1), String(character2)].joined()
```